# When DML occurs, how to log on another table what columns are affected, old value, and new value per record in SQL Server 2008 SE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-trigger, dml, audit-logging

Every time this question comes up, I feel like I go down the rabbit hole of different solutions and methods, but in the end, I'm not sure what to actually use. Every solution ends with comments at the bottom stating why isn't right or why it's dangerous.

I thought CDC would be answer I was looking for but then I learned that our version is SE and it's not supported.

So I guess I'll add to the other numerous questions asked on this topic in the hope that I can get a solution to work for my needs.

Here is what I'm trying to get:

I have a table of this form:

```
| Item | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | ... | F30 |
```

This table can be altered via INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

I'm looking to log any DML actions to a table of this form:

```
| TimeStamp | Action | Item | Column Affected | Old Value | New Value |
```

One of the criticisms I ran across against trigger based logging was that they didn't make it to be "set" based. As an example for DMLs that have batches of changes vs simple one line statements. In my case, I know for sure the DML statements are always of the form: (Always a separate DML statement for any Item and very specific on what column.)

```
[DML_Command] [Table_Name] SET [Column_Name] = [Value] WHERE [Item] = 'Unique_Item_Name'
Ex. UPDATE Item_tbl SET F3 = 620 WHERE Item = 'Unique_Item_Name'
```

So I'm hoping if an Update statement like the above occurs, I get a new record or row in the Logging table like:

```
| TimeStamp | Action | Item | Column Affected | Old Value | New Value |
| 9/25/2018 2:02:00:00 PM | 'Update' | 'Unique_Item_Name' | 'F3' | NULL | 620 |
```

One of the things I'm afraid will make this not work is if there is no way to dynamically capture the column so that I don't have to record the entire row every time it logs. I'd like it to log the column and the value changes to keep the logging table simple and easier for analysis.

I'd appreciate any input on this. Even a shove in the right direction will help. Thanks for your time!

Comment: First of all `TimeStamp` is a datatype, try to avoid naming columns/objects with a reserverd words to prevent mistakes and errors, 2nd what's wrong with `TRIGGER`? and did you think to use Audit instead or SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: In a trigger, you can use `UPDATE()` to test if a column is affected, and `COLUMNS_UPDATED` to get all columns affected (though the latter is much more involved, because manipulating bitmasks in T-SQL is clumsy). It pays off to write these triggers to handle set-based updates no matter how sure you are about the form of the statements -- it's really not much harder than single rows.

Comment: I've done this many times before, using triggers. As @JeroenMostert says, *always* make them set based. You will be caught for sure otherwise when someone does some sort of maintenance job down the track. Its very easy to save the whole row into an audit table, either just write the *before* row or the *after* row (either way you can get the matching row by looking at the next/previous row in the audit table or the live table). If you want to also get the column changed, then you can do this as a second task on the audit table so as not to affect performance of updates.

Comment: What is the purpose of the log? Is it to allow the user to easily see change history of a given record or for more general change tracking?

Comment: Instead of triggers, you can implement soft-delete, so keeping in the same table the older versions for each row. The benefits are that it's much simpler to implement and have less of a performance hit on insert/update/deletes, the downside it that it massively increases your storage size, so much that it potentially has a noticeable effect on select performance (that can be minimized using filtered indexes).